# Plotting of multi-lists function versus two variables of one list

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How to plot **3D graph** for the function **Q** Versus **x** and **y** given by the following sample code:

```
x=Table[x,{x,0,10}]
y=Table[y,{y,0,10}]
Q=Table[Sqrt[x[[m]]^2+y[[n]]^2,{m,1,11},{n,1,11}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure your sticking point, but you can use the `Outer[ ]` function to take the outer product of two vectors (and other things), saving you the table to make `Q`

```
outprod = Outer[Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2] &, x, y];

outprod == Q
(* True *)
```

Then plot it.

```
ListPlot3D[outprod ]
```

[image]

EDIT

In case this is what you want...capture the `x` and `y` coords with the pts

```
op3 = Outer[{#1, #2, Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2]} &, x, y]
```

Generate the lines

```
lines = Line /@ op3;
Graphics3D[lines]
```

[image]

Set up the data for 3D plotting

```
plotPts = Partition[Flatten@op3, 3];
```

Show the lines with the 3D plot

```
Show[ListPlot3D[plotPts, Mesh -> None], Graphics3D@{Thick, Blue, lines}]
```

[image]

Since your lines are for fixed `x`, you can also just manipulate the mesh in the plot

```
ListPlot3D[plotPts, Mesh -> {x, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: In my question, I obtained a list of  Q with x  for each element of the list  y. In 2D graph I obtained 11 curves of Q with x against 11 values of y. Now I need to convert the 2D graph to 3D one @Mike Y

Comment: thank you for the last editing,  the idea works, But the Outer function do not give the right results like the Table function. They are different. @Mike Y

Comment: The new `Outer` doesn't because I add in the `x` and `y` values, otherwise it is an exact match, as demonstrated with the `outprod == Q` check before the edit. Best of luck!

Comment: yes, you alright.... thank very much